# SD card not mounted (Android app dev in eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sd-card

I am new to android development with Eclipse and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to configure my application so it can be able to read/write text to a virtual SD card.

I have done a lot of google'ing and have found bits and pieces, but I still feel like I'm missing something that's making it not work.

In my manifest I have included:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \>
```

Here is my code:

```
String state=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        data.setText("SD card not mounted");
    else
    {
        File externalDir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File textFile=new File(externalDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"text.txt");
        try
        {
            writeTextFile(textFile, "this is a test\n LINE BREAK");
            String text=readTextFile(textFile);
            data.setText(text);
            if(!textFile.delete())
            data.setText("couldn't remove temporary dir");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            data.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

 private void writeTextFile(File file, String text) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    writer.write(text);
    writer.close();
}
private String readTextFile(File file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        text.append(line);
        text.append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return text.toString();
}
```

I have the first part of the code in a button click function, and the "data" variable is for an editText view.
Everytime I run it and click the button, I get the result "SD card not mounted".

I know I'm missing an important step somewhere to get this to functioning properly. Can anyone help me out, please?
Thank you!

Comment: You say "virtual SD card" so I'm assuming this is with the emulator and not a real device? And you've configured the AVD for the emulator to use a virtual SD card?

Comment: At this point I feel really dumb. Yes I'm using an emulator.
And I just realized I had to edit the AVD to use a virtual SD card. I had such a hard time understanding that when reading it in instructions. Well it's working now.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: lol, no problems. A little over a year ago I'd never used eclipse, the emulator or programmed for Android. It's a tough learning curve and we've all got to start somewhere. One tip - specify a small(ish) SD card size (just enough for what you need). If you specify 1GB (for example), the emulator will eat that much memory on your dev machine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Yeah I've got a lot of learning to do. Coming from Visual Studio C# development this is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this problem coz your emulator might not be configured correctly to use (or provide) SD Card functionality.

I would hence suggest you to visit the AVD Manager > **Edit** AVD > Specify the size of the SD Card you require.

Also dont forget to add Hardware Property to the same avd . Select New > "**SD Card Support**" > set it to *true*.

I think this will solve the problem. If it still pertains - do report here! **Good Luck!** :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with a new android 6.+ avd where I did not setup the sdcard when I started the avd for the first time. It did not create the symlink properly.

It was symlinked to the following: `/mnt/user/0/primary`

Here are the symlinks

```
/sdcard -> /storage/self/primary
cd /storage/self
ls -la
primary -> /mnt/user/0/primary
cd /mnt/user/0/
```

There was no primary directory created. I recreated the avd and went through the process of setting up the sdcard and now life is great!